Pushing Tags in Azure Devops Via Powershell Commands Doesn't Set Tagger Information
Hi I have a release that automatically tags the release commit in the source repo via some git commands in a powershell script.  Its below:
cd $(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\_repo_root
git checkout $(Build.SourceVersion)
git tag $(RELEASE_TAG)
git push --tags

Write-Host tagged $(RELEASE_TAG) on commit $(Build.SourceVersion)

It does correctly tag the release commit, however in the ADO tags ui it doesn't show any tagger information:

4.1.0 was added manually through the ADO dialog but the releases > 4.2 were created through the script above.  Is there a way to provide this information to ADO from a script in a release pipeline?

Can you detect those differences locally, too? How do they appear, prefebly in terms of git CLI output? Further, can you reproduce this locally? What is the user running those commands? That said, there are so-called annotated and lightweight tags, does that explain the difference?

yes I can run that powershell above and create and push tags on the ADO repo via git commands but the extra information of when the tag was committed and who created it,  is never added to the tags UI in ADO

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado -- that TLA is already taken. ;)

I can reproduce the same with your code in release pipeline:

This is because Lightweight tags are displayed with a tag name and commit, only Annotated tags are displayed with a tag name, message, commit, tagger, and creation date(doc link).

Please add comment when you add tag: git tag $(RELEASE_TAG) -m "test tag".
In addition, you are using Scoped build identities whose token is $(system.accesstoken) to push the tag to the repo,  the identity doesn’t include personal information like name or email. You need to add the user info with git config command.
The code below works:
cd "$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\_repo_root"
git checkout $(Build.SourceVersion)
git config --global user.name "testuser"            # add user info and email
git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"
git tag $(RELEASE_TAG) -m "test tag"                # add comment for tag
git push --tags
Write-Host tagged $(RELEASE_TAG) on commit $(Build.SourceVersion)

It has the tagger info as below:


Add more :
In release pipeline, tick the option Allow scripts to access the OAuth token to allow the git command to use the scoped build identity.

There are two type scoped build identities as mentioned in above link, my sample below for your reference. On project setting, confirm the identity, it's project-scoped build identity({Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})) on my side.

On target repo which you would add tag, grant the permission for the identity.


How do you provide credentials for the git user.name you provide in the script?  I'm getting authentication issues when I try your solution and am trying to figure out how to provide the script with the necessary credentials.

In your release pipeline, stage->agent job-> tick the option Allow scripts to access the OAuth token, so that git command will use it to add tags. I will edit with details.

Thanks that seemed to do it although I updated the push command to this:
git push https://:$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/MYORG/MYPROJECT/_git/MYREPO --tags

Glad to know it works. Yes, you can use the identity in push command too. Happy coding!
